# Why isn't clover generating JSON from my pom.xml config?

Tags: java, maven, clover

I have this bit in my `pom.xml`

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>clover-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <generateJson>true</generateJson>
                <generateXml>true</generateXml>
                <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
                <generatePdf>true</generatePdf>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I know PDF & JSON default to false. The others default to true.

Somehow when I do this, I generate HTML, XML, and even the PDF. JSON is nowhere to be found. It even says `Generating JSON report to: /example/myrepo/target/site/clover`, as it does for the XML. When I go to that folder I see `clover.pdf` and `clover.xml`. No `clover.json`.

If I do the following, it strangely says `No report being generated for this module.` and then `Generating JSON report to: /example/myrepo/target/site/clover`.

```
<configuration>
    <generateJson>true</generateJson>
    <generateXml>false</generateXml>
    <generateHtml>false</generateHtml>
    <generatePdf>false</generatePdf>
</configuration>
```

If I do this, it goes back to generating reports just "fine" (this example will just create the XML, no HTML). Still no JSON

```
<configuration>
    <generateJson>true</generateJson>
    <generateXml>true</generateXml>
    <generateHtml>false</generateHtml>
    <generatePdf>false</generatePdf>
</configuration>
```

Full config (with some things swapped to stay anon)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.583</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mynamespace</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>

    <name>Test</name>
    <description>Test</description>
    <url>https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TODO+Plugin</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>clover-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateJson>true</generateJson>
                        <generateXml>true</generateXml>
                        <generateHtml>false</generateHtml>
                        <generatePdf>false</generatePdf>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**Update**
I ran `java -Dclover.license.path=/Users/dstein/Desktop/clover.lic -cp "/Users/dstein/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/clover/clover/4.1.2/*" com.atlassian.clover.reporters.json.JSONReporter -i target/clover/clover.db -o clover_json -d`

It generated my folder and threw a lot of JS files in it. Those files sometimes have JSON... but are wrapped in what looks like JSONP cause it will be like `processClover({})`. Is this expected behavior? Is the fact they call it JSON a misnomer?

Comment: are you certain of inheriting this plugin configuration to the module where you expect the generation to occur? Could you share the hierarchy of your modules and explain where is the Json not geting generated?

Comment: I am able to disable the html and xml, as well as enable pdf, so wouldn't that prove it is inheriting this config properly? I do not see it within the folder that Clover says it's generating at `target/site/clover` where the other generations sit.

Comment: *able to disable the html and xml, as well as enable pdf, so wouldn't that prove* it would, the question didn't read it. Also could you share a minimal project to reproduce this?

Comment: Added more context + whole pom.xml. Not sure that we'd need whole project cause my project is just one file and one test file.

Comment: Basically, everything generates properly for 3 of 4 formats so it wouldn't make sense that my Foo.java or Foo.class would be the cause. Must be something between Clover & Maven

Comment: @DaveStein Can you generate manually the JSON report via JsonReporter via CLI? I wonder if it's the problem with JSON reporter itself or configuration Maven-Reporter 

https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/jsonreporter-417367537.html

Comment: Thanks @grzlew I'll take a look

Comment: Okay maven output `/Users/dstein/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/clover/clover/4.1.2/clover-4.1.2.jar` but when I do `java -cp "/Users/dstein/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/clover/clover/4.1.2/*" com.atlassian.clover.reporters.json.JSONReporter` it says I have no license. When running through maven it knows I am still on trial, and then I'm doubly confused cause I thought it's open sourced now.

Comment: I modified my settings.xml file to know whre to find license file when using maven... but not sure how to accomplish this when just doing `java` straight up

Comment: You have to use the Ant way... `java -Dclover.license.path=/Users/dstein/Desktop/clover.lic -cp "/Users/dstein/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/clover/clover/4.1.2/*" com.atlassian.clover.reporters.json.JSONReporter` works

Comment: Also posted https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Clover-questions/Why-doesn-t-JSON-Reporter-output-JSON/qaq-p/633579#M1568, now that I was able to jsut straight up test this clover class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that this feature should have been called JSONP.

[The docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/json-reference-132382959.html?_ga=2.206875223.552966553.1504621537-1360958930.1484167326) show that it is meant to output all those JS files to be consumed by a callback on a webpage. It's not meant to be used for parsing, as you can do with the XML.